# VB6 application won't load DLL outside of debugger

Tags: dll, vb6

I'm attempting to make some changes to a legacy VB6 application to work with a new version of software which has been installed and deployed.  I've worked through all of the apparent issues in getting my build environment set up to the point where I can debug, and produce executables and DLLs.  Unfortunately, I'm seeing some *very* strange behavior when I run the application *outside* of the debugger, and I can't seem to figure out what's going on.

When running the executable and the main DLL inside the debugger (in a Project Group), everything works as expected.
When running the built executable and DLL outside the debugger, a secondary DLL (referenced by the main DLL) never loads into memory, and I get a null reference exception on the line that calls into a method on an object in the second DLL.

```
Object variable or With block variable not set

Number:  91(2147221595)
Source:  [ManifestForm.cmdPrintLabel_Click] [Manifest.PrintCurrentBoxLabel] 
[Manifest.ShipBox] 
[Manifest.PrintBoxLabel] 
[RateServer.PrintProgisticsLabel] - Line:2126
```

Line 2126 is a call out a method on an object exposed through the second DLL, which has, by that point in time, already been allocated and initialized.

Unable to figure out what was going on, I started putting 'debug' message boxes in the called method, and the error shows up *before* the message box on the first line of the function.  The object which has the method is not Nothing (I checked that), and further investigation revealed that the second DLL is never loaded into memory for the executable's process when running outside of the debugger.

The primary DLL references the only registered copy of the second DLL. (It is currently *literally* the only copy of the DLL on my system.)

I'm stuck trying to figure out why the DLL doesn't want to load.

Comment: Is your DLL correctly registered and does the registry point to the correct physical path of your DLL?

Comment: Well, when I register it it *says* it registered successfully.

Comment: And...  It started working 3 days after I posted this question.  No changes to the project file, no reboot of the system between failed runs and the successful run.  No idea what caused the problem, or what solved it.

Comment: Good deal - one has to appreciate a well-behaved random error.